# LWJGL is ContextArribs Needed when making the display?

Tags: lwjgl

I have a problem and I have looked every where, so I am going to ask it: Do you need ContextAttribs? I have this error when I run my program:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not create context (WGL_ARB_create_context)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.create(WindowsContextImplementation.java:50)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:797)
at renderEngine.DisplayManager.createDisplay(DisplayManager.java:22)
at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:10)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine close requested state of uncreated window
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.isCloseRequested(Display.java:549)
at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:12)
```

This is my code(Main class):

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayManager.createDisplay();

    if (Display.isCloseRequested())
        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
    while (true)
    {
        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
    }
}
```

Display Class:

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextAttribs;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;
import org.omg.CORBA.Context;


public class DisplayManager {

private static final int WIDTH = 1200;
private static final int HEIGHT = 650;
private static final int FPS_CAP = 60;

public static void createDisplay()  { 
    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withProfileCore(true).withForwardCompatible(true);

    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), new ContextAttribs(3,2).withProfileCore(true).withForwardCompatible(true));
        Display.setTitle("Knights of the Lord's Realm");
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void updateDisplay() { 
    Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
}
public static void closeDisplay() { 
    Display.destroy();
}

}
```

Any ideas other than graphics card issue or even if I have to use "ContextAttribs"
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withProfileCore(true).withForwardCompatible(true);
```

I'm assuming that you are follow "ThinMatrix" Youtube tutorial replace that line with
`ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2);
 attribs.withForwardCompatible(true);
 attribs.withProfileCompatibility(true);`